# opencv_createsamples on Windows continues to run without any output

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am running opencv_createsamples on Windows machine. I do not get any error but the utility continues to run without giving any output. I have positive marked up images which I am passing to the command in a form of a file marker.dat

Following is the command I am using

```
    opencv_createsamples -info "C:\Python27\marker.dat" -vec "C:\Python27\op.vec" -show -w 24 -h 24
```

The contents of the market.dat are as follows:

lines1.jpg 1 56 111 621 55

lines2.jpg 1 2184 186 603 79

I do not get any error. The program says "Create training samples from images collections" but nothing happens after that. It continues to remain in the same state forever.

Am I missing anything here? I tried to do lot of search on google but could not find any resolution. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create samples should not run forever, normally it whips through all your data and creates the output

Comment: The problem got solved. Actually it was quite silly on my part to put the absolute paths in " ". I removed them and it started working. Since the program does not throw any error it was quite hard to find out what was happening.

Comment: Noice. You should post this as the answer incase somebody else comes looking for this solution.